# hi..Android facebook app sharing not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am new to android facebook app sharing,I want to make app sharing demo using android ,And have made a demo using [Faceboook app sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#interfaces)

I have tried step by step,My code is as below,But It gives me error that ApplicatioID Parametere must not null,I am having my appId,But I dont know where to pass it as parameter.My code is:

```
package com.example.appsahre;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.WebDialog.OnCompleteListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android").build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        publishFeedDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data,
                new FacebookDialog.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(
                            FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                        Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
                            Exception error, Bundle data) {
                        Log.e("Activity",
                                String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
                    }

                });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        params.putString("caption",
                "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
        params.putString(
                "description",
                "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        params.putString("picture",
                "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(
                MainActivity.this, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values
                                    .getString("1429518160643697");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }

                }).build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

include a meta-data tag in your manifest file like this:

```
   <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
          android:value="YOUR_APP_ID" />
```

This meta-data should be a child of your Application tag